# Weird exception using RhinoMocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, rhino-mocks

I have the following code:

```
// Arrange
IUnityContainer container = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IUnityContainer>();
container.Expect(c => c.Resolve<IServiceContainerRegistrar>());
```

This fails with:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy86130865210b4541862c5857c50c162c' to type
>   'Omron.Cxap.Modules.Drives.Services.Common.IServiceContainerRegistrar'.

If I add the following line it works:

```
// Arrange
IUnityContainer container = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IUnityContainer>();
container.Expect(c => c.RegisterType<IServiceContainerRegistrar, ServiceContainerRegistrar>());
container.Expect(c => c.Resolve<IServiceContainerRegistrar>());
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug on Rhino?

Comment: Does `Expect` not only test that something was called, but the order in which is was called? Maybe you want to use `AssertWasCalled` instead?

Comment: As this is a Stub not a Mock it shouldn't fail right?

Comment: That's what I would have thought... is it really necessary to test this? Is your class you're testing directly using Unity? If so, you're coupling your class to an IoC container which is probably bad. I recommend constructor injection instead ;)

Comment: We are using construction injection but this is the main module (the entry point) so we are using the container to share objects between completely decoupled prism modules. Anyway I'm coupled with the interface, not the class.

Comment: Gotcha, so you're testing the entry-point to confirms it's doing the right thing in putting the pieces together and get things going?

Comment: That's right buddy. I lke to have 100% coverage so that's why I'm testing this.